# How to provide data to app

Tags: android, io, hashmap, assets

I have to design an android app that animate some points through a big set of data files that store the positions at various times. What is the best practice to provide data to apps?

I'm putting txt data files in asset folder, and every time I start the app data are read in some HashMap to have a faster access during runtime. The problem is that the upload of data into the HashMap is a bit slow.

I'm searching for a method that stores data in a "database" the first time and then there's no more need to read from text files every time.

I don't know SQL or similar stuff, but if it is the right thing to do I will learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for Storing data in Android is by using Sqlite as database
you simply create your own and add your data in your tables
yo can get started from here [SQLITEDB](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my ignorance, but the database is something that I have prepare externally from the app or there is something like a first time data production?

Comment: Don't be sorry, you can prepare it in a txt file and add it to your sqliteDatabase or start Adding data to your SliteDB from your first launch of the app

Comment: Still a question... What about the data reading speed? My points have to go around with a high frame rate so I have to read positions from database many times per second. Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible, the data access is fast with a sqliteDatabase, that's one of the reasons why databases exists it's faster than reading from a file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create SQLite Db

For first time check whethere your records in table are 0.
if zero than insert data from file to table otherwise if records are not zero leave it.